# Hive error message. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am using cloudera for a school project where we have to upload a data set into hive. I have recieved the following error message yesterday and cant seem to find the problem. Please note I am a beginner and any help would be appreciated.

[Error message from hive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onSle.png)

Comment: You should bring the error message into your question as text, in case the link breaks

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off Hadoop safe mode by using below command:

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
OR
$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it helped !